# Event-driven design in C++

Tags: c++, observer-pattern, event-driven-design

In my event-driven application I have common issue. Suppose following class diagram:

[image: class diagram]

I'm using observer pattern here. `Worker` and `WorkerManager` lives in the same thread. Now suppose sequence of actions:

1. `Worker` calls listener class to report result in the middle of method
2. `WorkerManager` (which is listener of `Worker`) decides to delete/modify `Worker` class
3. `Worker` continue execution of method, being **removed** of **modified**. Programmer must consider these situations, and it is complicated and error-prone.

In code it might look like that:

```
// in worker.cpp

void Worker::SomeMethod() {
    ...
    listener_->OnWorkDone(this); // removed here by listener
    workDone_ = true; // memory corruption
    ...
}


// in worker_manager.cpp

void WorkerManager::OnWorkerWorkDone(Worker* worker) {
    RemoveWorker(worker);
}
```

How it can be modified:

```
// in worker.cpp

void Worker::DoSomeWork() {
    workDone = false;
    ...
}

void Worker::SomeMethod() {
    ...
    listener_->OnWorkDone(this); // sets workDone to false here by DoSomeWork()
    workDone_ = true; // but SomeMethod doesn't aware of it
    ...
}


// in worker_manager.cpp

void WorkerManager::OnWorkerWorkDone(Worker* worker) {
    worker->DoSomeWork(); // do another work
}
```

Now I see these solutions to problem:

- Set by code style guide that listener class must be called last. But it quite fragile and error prone solution.
- Made sort of QT queued connections.

QT queued connections is made on meta-object system and it is way too much for my project. I need a simpler tool that would allow me to defer listener callbacks in thread's event loop.

I believe that this issue is common in event-driven design. Where can I see examples of how it can be handled?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking for here. What is the problem?

Comment: Plan (a) - don't remove worker threads - return them to a pool. (b) use an event function prototype that returns a value, (maybe an enum), that can give the work thread further instruction, eg 'terminate yourself'.  (c) don't design in stuff that can go wrong:(  (d) don't micro-manage 'worker threads' from some 'main/manager thread' - dangerous/avoidable/suckage.